# Expression is not resolved as expected in bash

Tags: bash

I need the expression in the script below to be resolved as true when `type` variable not equals to `parent` and the `parents` array contains the current element of the `children` array. Why is it always false? I expected it to print `dev-php skipped` when iterating over the first element of the `children` array.

The thing is that if I remove the right part of the expression so that it looks like `if [[ ${parents[*]} =~ ${d} ]] ; then`, it works as I need. What's wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

declare -a parents=(dev-php test1 test2)
declare -a children=(dev-php something-else)

type="child"

for d in ${children[@]} ; do
    echo "testing ${d}"

    if [[ ${parents[*]} =~ ${d} && ${type} -ne parent ]] ; then
        echo "${d} skipped"
    else
        echo "${d} NOT skipped"
    fi
done
```

Comment: There's some dubious string handling here. `for d in ${children[@]}` should have double-quotes around `${children[@]}` to prevent misparsing. Also, `${parents[*]} =~ ${d}` will match if `$d` is a substring of anything in the `parents` array (e.g. "test" would match "test1", "test1" would match "test10", etc.). Also, if `$d` contains any regex metacharacters, things can get really weird. I'd use `" ${parents[*]} " = *" $d "*` (which can fail if any items contain spaces, but that's not as bad as the current version).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Bash scripting is like a magic for me. What's the point of the spaces around `$d` and `${parents[*]}`?

Comment: To prevent matching *parts* of items. For example, "test" is a substring of "dev-php test1 test2", but " test1 " is not a substring of " dev-php test1 test2 ". bash has lots of oddities, but this it really just a bit of generic string-manipulation trickery. BTW, when you're learning shell scripting, I recommend [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) -- it'll point out a lot of common mistakes and save you headaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
${type} -ne parent
```

`-ne` is an arithmetic operator. Use `!=` for strings.

```
$type != parent
```

(No need for the curly braces.)